# Merge possible values to array when comparing two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I'm looking for a simple solution to merge two arrays. They both look mostly alike, except one key-value-pair. I want my result to have an array with both possible values.

The xdebugged arrays look like this (simplified):

```
array (size=3)
    'entry' => string '18' (length=2)        
    'mykey' => string 'value1' (length=6) // here is the difference
    'something' => string '1' (length=1)
array (size=3)
    'entry' => string '18' (length=2)        
    'mykey' => string 'value2' (length=6)) // here is the difference
    'something' => string '1' (length=1)
```

I'd like the result to be:

```
array (size=2)
    'entry' => string '18' (length=2)        
    'mykey' => array (size=2)) // both values merged to array
         '0' => 'value1' (length=6)
         '1' => 'value2' (length=6)
    'something' => string '1' (length=1)
```

How to achieve this easily?

Comment: I don't know of any built-in functions. You probably just have to create a loop that will go through and if there's a key with a different value replace it with an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this suffice:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    'entry'=>'18',
    'mykey'=>'value1',
    'something'=>'1'
);
$array2 = array(
    'entry'=>'18',
    'mykey'=>'value2',
    'something'=>'1'
);

$output = array();
foreach($array1 as $k=>$v){
    if(isset($array2[$k]) && $array2[$k] === $v){
        $output[$k] = $v;
    }elseif(isset($array2[$k])){
        $output[$k][] = array($v,$array2[$k]);
    }else{
        $output[$k] = $v;
    }
}

foreach($array2 as $k=>$v){
    if(!array_key_exists($k,$output)){
        $output[$k] = $v;
    }
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($output),'</pre>';
```

**Edit**:I do like the use of `array_merge_recursive()` mentioned by [Ziarno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1974132/ziarno), but the issue is that it will create an array for each key. So I have added the use of `array_unique()`, then checking if the length is 1, and flattening it if so.

```
$output = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);

foreach($output as $k=>&$v){
    $v = array_unique($v);
    if(count($v)==1){
        $v = $v[0];
    }
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($output),'</pre>';
```

Comment: What about keys that are only in `$array2`?

Comment: good point, I've added that in as well. It's a bit lengthy and I'm sure it could be improved on.

Comment: I thought close to your first idea, but its not that readable. So I'll use your second thought, which I just found out myself based on the hint to `array_merge_recursive`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own custom code for this.

```
// Get all the key values.
foreach($arrays as $array){
$keys[] = $array['mykey']
}

// retain 1st element & discard others.
$array = array_slice($arrays, 0, 1);

// update to the 1st array element
$array['mykey'] = $keys;

// print
print_r($array);
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) function is designed **exactly** for what you need:

`array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2)`